# However to return promise only if rejected?

Tags: javascript, promise

If I have 2 promises, and I want return promise 1 in promise 2 only if promise1 is rejected otherwise promise2 continues and returns Promise.resolve()
for explanation :

```
    const promise1 =(cond)=>{
    const x = true;
    
    if(!cond){
        
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Error'))
    }
     return Promise.resolve('Done')
} 

const promise2 =()=> { 

//i want to return promise1 if it rejected 
return promise1(false)
.then(res=>res)
.catch(e=>e)


//otherwise return Promise.resolve 
return Promise.resolve('ok') 


}
```

Comment: `return promise1(false).then(() => "ok").catch((err) => Promise.reject(err))`? Or you can write it using `async`/`await` syntax which might might the intent clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating it.

The Promise returned by the first function will follow its success path or its error path depending on whether `cond` was truthy or falsy. No test is needed in the second function, because Promises look after themselves in this regard.

Let's call the functions `f1` and `f2` (they are Functions not Promises).

`f1` can be written ...

```
const f1 = (cond) => {
    return cond ? Promise.resolve('Done') : Promise.reject(new Error('Error'));
}
```

And `f2` would be ...

```
const f2 = () => {
    return promise1(false)
    .then(res => 'OK'); // whatever the result is, deliver 'OK'.
    // No need to catch; error status, and its Error object, will naturally propagate to f2's caller.
}
```

Or, if you are happy for the result 'Done' not to be changed to 'OK', then simply write ...

```
const f2 = () => f1(false); // No need for .then() or .catch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is not healthy. Check this out:

```
const promise1 = cond => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    if(!cond){
        return reject(new Error('Error occur'));
    }
     return resolve('Done');
})
}

const promise2 = (cond) => {
   if(!cond) {
      //i want to return promise1 if it rejected 
      return promise1(cond)
      .then(res=>res)
      .catch(e=>{throw e});
   }


   //otherwise return Promise.resolve 
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     return resolve("ok");
   })
}





try {
  promise2(true).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
  promise2(false).catch(err => {
    throw err;
  })
} catch (error) {
  console.err(error.message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't depends on cond, I want depend on if the promise would get rejected then return